# createPattern from new image

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have a function which appends an image to the dom, creates a pattern from this image and returns this pattern to the outer code. The problem I face is that from time to time the function stops working. As far as I can gather, this happens because image loading is not so fast. So, when I call `ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat")`, `img` is not yet loaded.The whole code looks like so:

```
Constr.createImagePattern = function (canvas, img_id) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        img,
        pattern;
    if (document.getElementById("_" + img_id + "_")) {
        img = document.getElementById("_" + img_id + "_");
    } else {            
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.id = "_" + img_id + "_";
        img.src = "resources/backgrounds/_" + img_id + "_.png";
        img.style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
    return pattern;
};
```

I expect that some will probably advise to use `onload` event and some extra callbacks. But I should stress it, that I absolutely need to return `pattern` variable. So, the code must be synchronous. This is a strict requirement.

Comment: img.addEventListener("load",function(){...}

Comment: Please, have a look at my last paragraph: "I expect that some will probably advise to use onload .... ". There I explain why I can not use callbacks. I need to return from createImagePattern.

Comment: It cannot be synchronous because it has to load...

Comment: The only thing you could do would be waiting until the imahe is loaded and return then

Comment: Thank you, Jonas. I think, you are right!